# Choosing elements in an array randomly - satisfying conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, selection

I need help for my project. The following are the sample data.

```
populations = [[1 1]
               [1 1]
               [1 0]
               [1 1]]

score = [0, 4, 0, 6]
avail_res = [4, 4]
```

Code looks like this:

```
chromosome = []
for num in score:
    if num <= avail_res[0] and num != 0:
        chromosome = populations[score.index(num)]
        print(chromosome)

        if len(chromosome) > 1:
           k = random.choice(chromosome)
           chromosome_best = [k[1]]
           print(chromosome_best)

        else:
           chromosome_best = [chromosome]
           print(chromosome_best)
```

The objective is to find the best chromosome among the chosen chromosome/s. For the example above, since only `4` (score index 1) satisfies the condition in the code, it should give `chromosome best = [1 1]` from populations. In cases that there are more than one score that satisfy the condition, the code should choose the best_chromosome, randomly. For example, `score = [4, 2, 2, 6]`. I have three elements in score that satisfy the condition (4, 2, 2). Now, in choosing the best_chromosome in populations, the code can choose the one that is higher, which is 4 and give the corresponding value in populations.

The problem is whenever I try to run the code, for the chosen `chromosome_best = [1 0]` (just an example), The length that I am getting is `2`, which corresponds for 1 and 0. But my intent is just to get `length = 1 for [1 0]` and `3` if the chromosomes are `[1 0] [1 1] [1 0]`. In this way, I could use the code above and choose randomly.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest making `chromosome` a list of lists -- and maybe rename it `chromosomes` in order to make that clear.

Instead of `chromosome = populations[score.index(num)]`, use `chromosomes.append(populations[score.index(num)])`.

Here's the complete code fragment:

```
chromosomes = []
for num in score:
    if num <= avail_res[0] and num != 0:
        chromosomes.append(populations[score.index(num)])
        print(chromosomes)

        if len(chromosomes) > 1:
           k = random.choice(chromosomes)
           chromosome_best = k[1]
           print(chromosome_best)

        else:
           chromosome_best = chromosomes
           print(chromosome_best)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Aside from your comment, what I did was to make chromosome best a numpy array, since whenever I try to run the code, I get an output = [array([1, 0])].